# react and spring boot cors error for axios.patch

Tags: reactjs, spring

I'm making my own miniproject by using React + Spring boot.
But I encountered the problem.

it's cors problem!

I wanted to use patch, put, delete functions that are not simple request like this.

***react -> requesting request to spring boot from saga...***

```
function likePostAPI(data) {
    const accessToken = cookies.get("accessToken");
    const userEmail = cookies.get("userEmail");
    const newObj = {
        email : userEmail
    };
    console.log("data :", data);
    return axios.patch(`/auth/post/${data}/like`, newObj,{
        headers:{
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          
        },
        withCredentials : true
    });
}
```

If i send request to spring boot, they must answer it because in my thought i already set up all the setting for cors.

***DemoApplication***

```
package miniproject.demo;

import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class DemoApplication {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory() {

        return new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return () -> Optional.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig.class

```
package miniproject.demo.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import miniproject.demo.jwt.JwtAccessDeniedHandler;
import miniproject.demo.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import miniproject.demo.jwt.TokenProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsUtils;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final JwtAccessDeniedHandler jwtAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    // h2 database 테스트가 원활하도록 관련 API 들은 전부 무시
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**", "/favicon.ico");
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // CSRF 설정 Disable
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()

                // exception handling 할 때 우리가 만든 클래스를 추가
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDeniedHandler)

                // h2-console 을 위한 설정을 추가
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin()

                // 시큐리티는 기본적으로 세션을 사용
                // 여기서는 세션을 사용하지 않기 때문에 세션 설정을 Stateless 로 설정
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

                // 로그인, 회원가입 API 는 토큰이 없는 상태에서 요청이 들어오기 때문에 permitAll 설정
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()   // 나머지 API 는 전부 인증 필요

                // JwtFilter 를 addFilterBefore 로 등록했던 JwtSecurityConfig 클래스를 적용
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtSecurityConfig(tokenProvider));
    }


    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET.name());
        configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT.name());
        configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE.name());
        configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PATCH.name());
        configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST.name());
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);

//        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
//        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
//        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
//        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
//        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
//        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
//        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

at first, request is denied!
But another requests for get, post are working properly. Right after i started to use patch, delete request, cors error emerged again.
[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]
I wonder what is the real problem for this. Of course i must miss something but it's not that simple. Please somebody help me!

image => [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaNBm.png

image => [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DVrO.png

here's my error msg from chrome...

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/post/135/like' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
post.js:95 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:117)
xhr.js:210 PATCH http://localhost:8080/auth/post/135/like net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Sometimes the cors error is not a real cors error, but it could be another error in the api that the browser is interpreting as a cors error. Did you check the logs to check if it is a real cors error?

Comment: Here!  
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/post/135/like' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
post.js:95 Error: Network Error at createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:117)
xhr.js:210 PATCH http://localhost:8080/auth/post/135/like net::ERR_FAILED    and please watch my images posted on my content!

Comment: I suggest you to use the spring annotation to allow cors: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/. It could be a misconfiguration, but I'm not practical with spring

Comment: still not working... but, thank you for your help :)